# Will the erase function of set in C++ change the address of other elements?

Tags: c++, set, erase

I have the following code:

```
set<Key> test;
test.insert(key1);
test.insert(key2);
iter1 = test.find(key1);
iter2 = test.find(key2);
test.erase(iter1);
```

My question is, if key1 is deleted, now can I use iter2 to refer to key2 in test?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, set's `erase` invalidates only iterators that point to the element that was erased (note that this is not necessarily true for all containers).

Comment: Thank you for replying so soon~ and what if after erase key1, I insert another key3 into test? Can I still use iter2 to refer to key2?

Comment: @user508305: Yes, insert doesn't invalidate iterators as well.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking you have to check the return value of the "insert" operation and ensure that `key1` and `key2` don't compare equal; otherwise `iter1 == iter2` and erasing `iter1` invalidates `iter2`. But in general see the previous answer, erasing an iterator invalidates only that iterator and no others.

Example:

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo(std::string s = "") : s(s) { }
  bool operator<(const Foo & other) { return s.size() < other.size(); }
}

std::set<Foo> x;
x.insert(Foo("Cat"));
x.insert(Foo("Dog")); // booboo
```

Answer (score 3):

Asociative containers set, multiset, map and multimap are required to only invalidate iterators and references to the erased elements.

In a deque all the iterators and references are invalidated, unless the erased members are at an end (front or back) of the deque (23.2.1.3/4),
in a list only the iterators and references to the erased element is invalidated (23.2.2.3/3) and on a vector every iterator and reference after the point of erase is invalidated (23.2.4.3/3)

Comment: Do you have a standard reference please for the associative container rules?

Comment: Yes, that would be `23.1.2 / 8` [lib.associative.reqmts] `The insert members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container, and the erase
members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.`